# Highstock Update Data getJson

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I'm new to Javascript and got the following Code working:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Temperatur</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {

    $.getJSON('sqltojson.php', function (data) {
        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector: {

                allButtonsEnabled: true,
                buttons: [{
                    type: 'minute',
                    count: 60,
                    text: 'hour',
                    dataGrouping: {
                        forced: true,
                        units: [['minute', [1]]]
                    }
                }, {
                    type: 'minute',
                    count: 360,
                    text: '6 hour',
                    dataGrouping: {
                        forced: true,
                        units: [['minute', [1]]]
                    }
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'all',
                    dataGrouping: {
                        forced: true,
                        units: [['minute', [1]]]
                    }
                }],
                buttonTheme: {
                    width: 60
                },
                selected: 0
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Temperatur'
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Temperatur',
                type: 'spline',
                data: data,
                color: '#0000FF',
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '°C'
                }

            }]
        });
    });

});
$(function () {

    $.getJSON('sqltojson2.php', function (data) {
        // Create the chart
        $('#container2').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector: {

                allButtonsEnabled: true,
                buttons: [{
                    type: 'minute',
                    count: 60,
                    text: 'hour',
                    dataGrouping: {
                        forced: true,
                        units: [['minute', [1]]]
                    }
                }, {
                    type: 'minute',
                    count: 360,
                    text: '6 hour',
                    dataGrouping: {
                        forced: true,
                        units: [['minute', [1]]]
                    }
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'all',
                    dataGrouping: {
                        forced: true,
                        units: [['minute', [1]]]
                    }
                }],
                buttonTheme: {
                    width: 60
                },
                selected: 0
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Luftfeuchte'
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Luftfeuchte',
        type: 'spline',
                data: data,
                color: '#FF0000',
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '%'
                }
            }]
        });
    });

});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
<div id="container2" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I now want to get both of the graphs into one Chart, and it should Update every Minute.
At the Moment I have two php scripts. One for [Timestamp, Temperature] and ohne for [Timestamp, Humidity].

I tried several Code snippets I found here, but i couldn't change it to my needs, because of my not present Javascript knowledge.

Could someone please give me a hint what I should try, or where I could find something that explains what I have to do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setInterval() to run your javascript every time interval as you choose.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

is a good tutorial to get to know how it's done.
I hope rest you can do from your current javascript knowledge. Name current two functions, run it inside another function defined inside setInterval function.

If you want to draw two charts on top of each other, pass it as a two-D array to HighChart. 
http://www.highcharts.com/demo 
contains lot of examples, and you can follow that.

For example,pass an array to a function which contains your code to draw the graph, then use that variable to give value to series.

```
function draw_first_chart(div_id,x_axis,data_input)
{
    $(div_id).highcharts({
        chart: {
        // ..//
    },
        title: {
            // ..//
        },

        xAxis: {
            // ..//
            },
            categories: x_axis
        },
        yAxis: {
            // ..//

        },
        tooltip: {
           // ..//
        },
        legend: {
            // ..//
        },
        series: data_input

    });
```

Here, if you want to display finite values in x axis, send an array to variable x_axis and other data to data_input as an array. If not just ignore variable x_axis and pass an array to data_input. Make sure in the

```
      data_input[i]['name']
```

should contain all graph titles (Humidity, Tempreture) and

```
      data_input[i]['data']
```

contains data. i is the number for each graph.

Hope this helps.